# [Java][org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, selenium

My server's env is:

1. Linux: Centos 6
2. JDK: 1.7.0_79
3. Tomcat: 7.0
4. Selenium-java: 2.42.2
5. MySQL: 5.5
6. Hibernate: 3.2.3

and Tomcat JVM Options:

JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Djava.awt.headless=true"

When I running testNG + Selenium, I will collect  selenium action & logs , save them into MySQL database. The tomcat server's     jvm crash with following errors:

```
I2017/05/23-03:28:07 >>  WARN >> Timer-3 >> com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector.run(    ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:608) >> com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@6623fb10 --     APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
[WARN] 2017-05-23 03:28:07.477 AM Timer-3 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner]
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@6623fb10 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads     for unassigned pending tasks!

Exception in thread "Thread-101" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "AppWorkManager-DbChecker(-34517d96:15c2db22842:-8000#19.14.5.83#autoNodeService)" java.lang.    OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2017/05/23-03:29:00 >>  INFO >> Thread-48 >> com.mydomain.utf.webui.util.WebDriverUtil.switchToTheOnlyWindow(WebDriverUtil.    java:415) >> 当前有多个窗口，没有指定的话默认不做窗口切换！
[INFO] 2017-05-23 03:29:00.206 AM Thread-48 [com.mydomain.utf.webui.util.WebDriverUtil]
当前有多个窗口，没有指定的话默认不做窗口切换！

2017/05/23-03:29:00 >>  WARN >> Timer-3 >> com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector.run(    ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:624) >> com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@6623fb10 --     APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Managed Threads: 3
Active Threads: 3
Active Tasks: 
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@219d9a2c (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@71f4cff1 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7f8011a9 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
Pending Tasks: 
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@3107afa4
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.setLastAcquisitionFailure(BasicResourcePool.java:194)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1000(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1834)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1026)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1026)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)


[WARN] 2017-05-23 03:29:00.213 AM Timer-3 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner]
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@6623fb10 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@219d9a2c (com.mchange.v2.async.    ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@71f4cff1 (com.mchange.v2.async.    ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7f8011a9 (com.mchange.v2.async.    ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@3107afa4
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.setLastAcquisitionFailure(BasicResourcePool.java:194)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1000(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1834)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1026)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1026)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)



Exception in thread "QuartzScheduler_UniEAP_Scheduler-iZ88zw4q2d8Z1495415264092_ClusterManager" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java     heap space
...
...
...


java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:202)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:246)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:227)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.readSocket(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:430)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:802)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:827)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:287)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:438)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.ria.io.impl.DataCenterReaderImpl.parse(DataCenterReaderImpl.java:40)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.ria.action.BaseEntry.generateContext(BaseEntry.java:175)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.ria.common.action.CommonProcessor.commonMethod(CommonProcessor.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:892)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1294)
at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1370)
at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:315)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:346)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:313)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:430)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:290)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:251)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:168)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.mydomain.unieap.core.fileupload.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.doIntercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:49)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:140)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.mydomain.unieap.core.exception.UniEAPExceptionInterceptor.intercept(UniEAPExceptionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:567)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.intercept.filter.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:125)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.intercept.filter.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:86)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:143)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.filter.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:25)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.accountpolicy.AccountPolicyFilter.doFilter(AccountPolicyFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilterHttp(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:102)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.ui.webapp.JCaptchaProcessingFilter.doFilter(JCaptchaProcessingFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.filter.SpecialCharFilter.doFilter(SpecialCharFilter.java:191)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at com.mydomain.unieap.techcomp.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:241)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.mydomain.unieap.core.filter.MultipartFormDataFileter.doFilter(MultipartFormDataFileter.java:43)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.mydomain.unieap.core.filter.UniEAPContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(UniEAPContextIntegrationFilter.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.mydomain.unieap.core.filter.IEModeFilter.doFilter(IEModeFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1719)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
May 23, 2017 4:53:47 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor doRun
SEVERE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

May 23, 2017 4:53:49 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller run
SEVERE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: why are you setting your memory so high?

Comment: yes, I think the settings is not right. so what do you have any idea?

Comment: try removing them completely